# How to add a event to google chart using angularjs with Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I'm using a ColumnChart and want to add click events on single Columns in the chart.
I'm using angularjs and the [ng-google-chart.js](https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart) Directive and Typescript.

Here is, how I initialize the chart:

```
$scope.chart = {};
$scope.chart.type = "ColumnChart";
$scope.chart.cssStyle = "";

$scope.$watch("data", () => {
$scope.chart.data = {
   //column and row definition
   };
});
$scope.chart.options = {
   //some chart options
   enableInteractivity: true,
   displayExactValues: true,
};
$scope.chart.formatters = {};
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', () => {
   alert("select event");
});
```

The event gets never fired and no errors are shown. Have I forgotten something with the Chart initialization?

Comment: I just had to remove the addListener call and add the selectHandler function from @Balrog30's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing the Google Charts API and the directive too much. Your chart object on scope is not an object recognized by the Google Charts API.  You can use the on-select attribute with angular-google-chart to achieve what you want.

```
$scope.selectHandler = function (selectedItem) {
  // Your logic here.
};

<!-- selectedItem is injected by name used here, so must be spelled correctly. -->
<div google-chart chart="chart" on-select="selectHandler(selectedItem)"></div>
```

You can find a more practical example in my blog post on [Hiding a Series](http://nicholasbering.ca/angularjs/2014/08/16/agc-hide-series/).

You can think of the chart object you put on scope as a template for building the google chart, but it is itself not recognized by the underlying library. All of the concepts map closely when you dig into the source code, though. They just don't match up by object reference.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I've needed. It works! :-)